# Windows version fails where jqplay.org works

Tags: json, windows, powershell, jq

I've been using jq to parse the output from AWS cli.

The output looks something like this..

```
{
"Vpcs": [
    {
        "CidrBlock": "10.29.19.64/26",
        "State": "available",
        "VpcId": "vpc-0ba51bd29c41d41",
        "IsDefault": false,
        "Tags": [
            {
                "Key": "Name",
                "Value": "CloudEndure-Europe-Development"
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

and the script I am using looks like this..

```
.Vpcs[] | [.VpcId, .CidrBlock,   (.Tags[]|select(.Key=="Name")|.Value)]
```

If I run it under Windows it fails like this.

> jq: error: Name/0 is not defined at , line 1:
> .Vpcs[] | [.VpcId, .CidrBlock, (.Tags[]|select(.Key==Name)|.Value)]
> jq: 1 compile error

But it works fine in jqplay.org.

Any ideas, on Windows Im using jq-1.6.

Thanks

Bruce.

Comment: You probably need to escape the quotes. So change the `select` to `select(.Key==\"Name\")`

Comment: I think it must be a bug in the Windows version, it works fine in on Linux.

Comment: Have you tried putting the program in a file and invoking jq with the -f option accordingly?

Comment: @BruceR, Re "*I think it must be a bug in the Windows version*", no, as already explained, it's the Windows command you built that's buggy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct jq program is

```
.Vpcs[] | [.VpcId, .CidrBlock, ( .Tags[] | select( .Key == "Name" ) | .Value ) ]
```

You didn't show the command you used, but you provided the following to `jq`:

```
.Vpcs[] | [.VpcId, .CidrBlock, ( .Tags[] | select( .Key == Name ) | .Value ) ]
```

That's incorrect. (Notice the missing quotes.)

Not only did you not provide what command you used, you didn't specify whether it was being provided to the Windows API (`CreateProcess`), Windows Shell (`cmd`) or Power Shell.

I'm guessing `cmd`. In order to provide the above program to `jq`, you can use the following `cmd` command:

```
jq ".Vpcs[] | [.VpcId, .CidrBlock, ( .Tags[] | select( .Key == \"Name\" ) | .Value ) ]" file.json
```

Comment: in fact I am using Powershell and I was using the quotes as I showed above. But using \ as an escape character works so thanks for that.

Comment: I didn't say you didn't provide quotes to PowerShell; I said you didn't provide quotes to `jq`. `jq` literally repeated the command you provided to it in the error message, and you can clearly see the quotes are missing.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not agreeing to ikegami about the CMD command that [he/she?] provided because the character used for CMD escaping is `^`, not `\` like Assembly/C/C++. I hope this will work (I don't want to test this on my potato thing):

```
jq .Vpcs[] | [.VpcId, .CidrBlock, ( .Tags[] | select( .Key == "Name" ) | .Value ) ] file.json
```

or this:

```
jq .Vpcs[] | [.VpcId, .CidrBlock, ( .Tags[] | select( .Key == ^"Name^" ) | .Value ) ] file.json
```

Comment: for the record, I'm using Powershell and neither of these work. But thanks for the reply

Comment: "He". ("They"/"them" has been acceptable pronouns for unknown gender for a hundred years, and still is. So you could have used that.) /// What I posted works in `cmd`. (I don't know why I said "should work" since I tested it.) /// And your snippets don't work in `cmd`. ("`'[.VpcId' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`")